# Cast function pointer from a C++ class to use it in C

Tags: c++, c, casting, function-pointers, point

I must cast a function pointer from a C++ class to hand over the function as parameter of a plain C function that only excpected pointers of void* and not Foo::void*.

Any ideas how to cast it?

```
   typedef void* (Foo::*from) (void*) ;
   typedef void* (*to)(void *);
```

The C++ function has the following signatur:

```
void* Foo::bar(void *ptr)
```

Best regards

Comment: Short answer: You can't.  Member functions need an object to be called on, and you lose that interface with a function pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to the similar question. Now I fixed it by using a static forwarding method that hast an objectpointer as parameter